# Changed www to subdomain, CodeIgniter function is still sending to www, gets 302 moved error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, iis-7

We recently got new website, but we have to keep some functionality on the old site. One of the functions is still reverting back to the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) instead of portal.domain.com. Everything other than this function is working properly. If I try to access the "owners login" it issues a 302 Temporarily Moved message in the web browser network logs and then tried the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and is able to complete the action.

[image: chrome network logs]

Here is what the headers look like:
[image: Headers detail]

I have tried to add a redirect to that specific function, have changed .htaccess for the whole site, have update web.config to redirect everything to the subdomain, have find/replaced all instances of [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) and replaced with portal.domain.com. Here are those files.

Here is the doOwnersLogin function

```
    public function doOwnersLogin()
{
        
     //$username = $this->input->post('username');
     //$p = $this->input->post('password');
     //$password=md5($p);
     //echo $step;
     //$this->session->set_userdata('team_id', $step);
     //$this->session->set_userdata('sub_page', 'fleet_home');
     $data = $this->owners_model->login();
     //print_r ($password);
     //exit;
     //print_r ($data);
     $this->load->library('user_agent');
     //$this->load->view('admin/access_fail');
     
     if ($data==0) {
         //$_SESSION['error']='User not found';
         $this->session->set_userdata('admin_message', 'User not found');
         $this->load->view('/owners/login');
     }
     else {
         //$_SESSION['logged_in']='1';
         //$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', '1');
         //$_SESSION['admin_logged_in']='1';
         $this->session->set_userdata('admin_logged_in', '3');
         //$_SESSION['error']='';
         $this->session->unset_userdata('error');
         redirect('/owners/');
     } 
     //$this->load->view('admin/access_fail', $data);

}
```

Here is the web.config

```
    <rewrite>
 <rules>
        <rule name="wwwtoportal" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://portal.domain.com/{R:0}/" />
         </rule> 
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

There is also a mySQL database attached to this config but I haven't been able to find anything in the DB that would redirect. Is there something in the DB that would cause this redirect?

Been banging my head at this one for a while. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: When you access the "owners login" it issues a 302 Temporarily Moved message. But the first image shows that owners login's status code is 200? DB is the connection between application and database, it cannot affect the redirection. Are you sure the rule can redirect all requests correctly?

Comment: The redirect rule redirects every part of that site except for this login. In the first image, it will try the portal.domain.com site, wait a bit, then 302, then 302 again, and then find 200 on the www.domain.com. As of right now there are both portal.domain.com and domain.com running from the same webhost.

Comment: So what you need is that it only redirects once and the status code is 302. Instead of returning to www.domain.com after two redirects, the status code is 200, right? If so, I suggest you enable [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to check why the url redirected twice.

Comment: Ideally, I wish to have it 200 on the portal.domain.com. I put in 301 redirect for everything on the site, but it jumps out of the portal.domain.com after getting the 302. The goal is to  have everything function on the portal.domain.com. 

I enabled tracing as you suggested, but I do not see any 302s in this log file.

Comment: Do the  www.domain.com and portal.domain.com bind to the same site? It seems that all requests to the rewrite rule will be redirected to portal.domain.com, including portal.domain.com. I'm not an expert on php, so I cannot make sure if the doOwnersLogin function correct. Please check it and configuration file of php again.